# MVCminiProfiler db profiler, how to get dbConnection with the entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, ado.net, mvc-mini-profiler

I'm trying to integrate the MVC-mini-Profiler into my mvc project to help profile the data calls.  I'm using the Entity Framework 4.1.  In the Profiler documentation is says use:

```
var conn = ProfiledDbConnection.Get(GetConnection());
```

The GetConnection() needs to return a System.Data.Common.DbConnection.  Does anyone know how to get the System.Data.Common.DbConnection from the current context?

http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options:

If you already have the EF Container created, you can do this:

```
var conn = (SqlConnection)((EntityConnection)efContainer.Connection).StoreConnection
```

If you are going to create EF container using a new connection, you can create a new connection using EF connection string like so:

```
var connectionString = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EFConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
DbConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString.ProviderConnectionString);
con = ProfiledDbConnection.Get(con);
return ObjectContextUtils.CreateObjectContext<EFContainer>(con);
```